# i have a problems with jQuery 1.7.2 and ajax params object passed with jsonp

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, object

i need a help with this code:

i need send service, data and content params... but does not work ((

```
var addons = {};
$.ajax({
    'url': 'http://site.com/index.php',
    dataType:'jsonp'
    success:function()
    {
        addons.name = 'Some name';
        addons.caption = 'Some caption';
        addons.description = 'Some description';
    }
});
var data = {
    'services'  :   1,
    'data'      :   addons,
    'content'   :   $(self).find('textarea').val()
};
$.ajax({
    'url'       :   'index.php',
    'dataType'  :   'json',
    'type'      :   'post',
    'data'      :   data,
    success:function(response){
        //...
    }
});
```

**Send Post:**

> services=1&content=hi

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, and what's happening instead?

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Is it supposed to do something?

Comment: check the flux capacitor

Comment: not send the parameter "data" look well

Comment: It does work. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ULe3D/) run it and check the network tab in the debugger, check form data in the header tab

Comment: @daveL, the code does work, but does not send the parameter "data" ((

Comment: I think the problem is that using "JSONP" ((

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the object´keys and values witin the brackets or you define an class like function and than save the values. But for your target the following should be working fine.

```
var addons = {
                 name: 'Some name', 
                 caption: 'Some caption',
                 description: 'Some description'
             };
```

Kind Regards

Comment: This is the same just other notation.